# java properties files, using a key as another keys value, is this possible

Tags: java

I would like to know if there is any way to use a key as another key's value in .properties files.

For example is this possible, or is there any other way to achieve something similar to this?

```
key = another_key

app.name=Stack Over Flow  
app.title.welcome=Welcome to {app.name}
```

so when i get the value of `app.title.welcome` it should be "`Welcome to Stack Over Flow`"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Apache Commons Configuration Project](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/index.html) has an implementation capable of doing variable interpolation.

Read the section named Variable Interpolation

```
application.name = Killer App
application.version = 1.6.2
application.title = ${application.name} ${application.version}
```

You would need this third-party library in your class path, but on the other hand you will not have to worry about writing yet another implementation for this :)

You might like to read the [Properties How To](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/user_guide.html) as well.

Comment: Unfortunatley a 404 on the Properties How To link.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/user_guide.html

Comment: Thanks @lainatnavi. I just updated the answer with your updated link.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/). It does what you're looking for and [more](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide-1.2/howto_properties.html).

Answer (score 1):

With `java.util.Properties` - no. But if you write the proper resolver - it is. And writing that resolver won't be that hard. Just look for `{..}` in each value and whenever encountered look for that key.

Comment: an abstract term that came to my mind. Any class that reads the file. It can be built ontop of java.util.Properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write `app.title.welcome=Welcome to {0}` and pass app.name as a parameter in Java code.